# Share dynamic variables between JS files in Electron/Node

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to get variables between files in an Electron App.

In index.html there's a input and a button, where i post an url.

```
//function.js

$('#tab_url').submit(function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var url = $("#url").val();
  console.log(url);
  if (url.indexOf('google.com') < 0) {
    message('no google', 'error this is no google');
    return false;
  }else {
    require('./apis/google');
  }
```

I want to do something like this.

```
//apis/google.js
console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a node.js question but basically `apis/google.js` needs to look like this

```
module.exports = (url) => {
    console.log(url);
}
```

And then `function.js` should look like this

```
$('#tab_url').submit(function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var url = $("#url").val();
  console.log(url);
  if (url.indexOf('google.com') < 0) {
    message('no google', 'error this is no google');
    return false;
  } else {
    require('./apis/google')(url);
  }
})
```